# How can i verify if my google web store application is licensed using asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, oauth, dotnetopenauth, chrome-web-store

I'm using DotNetOpenAuth.dll in order to obtain userid, but i don't know how to send the signed OAuth request google needs:

http://code.google.com/intl/it-IT/chrome/webstore/docs/check_for_payment.html

the example shows only java code

thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Go to http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/ and read the documentations, you should find everything you need there.

EDIT:
I'm not sure if this is the right way or not but here is some sample code in c#

```
var serviceProvider = new ServiceProviderDescription();
var tokenManager = new TokenManager(); //make an implementation of IConsumerTokenManager
var oauth = new WebConsumer(serviceProvider, tokenManager); //instanciate an consumer
var user = new User(); //User class contains an implementation of getFederatedIdentity()
var url = new Uri(string.Format(SERVER_URL,APP_ID,HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(user.getFederatedIdentity())));//create the url
var response = oauth.PrepareAuthorizedRequestAndSend(
    new MessageReceivingEndpoint(url, HttpDeliveryMethods.AuthorizationHeaderRequest), TOKEN); //Send the request
//do what you want with the response
```

Comment: i read it but i could find nothing about the google license system.
any suggest?

Comment: @Merlino I can't help you more than this, I've updated my answer with sample code of how it could look like in C#, but if there isn't enough info I suggest that you join their google group and ask questions there.

Comment: no response ... anywhere!
very strange. none uses google apps and asp.net?